# Calculating the max number of objects that can be in an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, max, equality

A utterly high-level overview of my project is to split x number of students into y classes while maintaining a roughly equal number of students in each class.

i.e. if there were 100 students and 5 classes (x = 100, y = 5), there should be 20 students in each class. For this situation, I could use the following code:

```
int maxNumberPerClass = x / y;
```

However, when there are 97 students and 5 classes, an issue arises with the above code. Yes there will be the same number of students in each class, but some students will not be placed given that there will need to be two classes of size 20 and three classes of size 19.

An incremental and somewhat hacky fix to this problem would yield four classes of size 20 and one class of size 17.

```
int maxNumberPerClass = ceil(x / y);
```

The problem with this method is that the last class (the last item in the array) will always contain the least number of students. This wouldn't be a problem if the deviation between this class and the other classes was just a single student. But as it's two in this case, it will be unfair.

What is the best way to split the X students into Y classes containing as equal a number of students as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int minNumberOfStudents = floor(x / y);
int maxNumberOfStudents = minNumberOfStudents + 1;
int numberOfClassesWithMaxStudents = x - (minNumberOfStudents * y);    
int numberOfClassesWithMinStudents = y - numberOfClassesWithMaxStudents;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am I correct in saying that I'd use your method in the following way: https://gist.github.com/MaxKramer/c9efd21eaff64ab0982a

Comment: Yes, you need to generate `numberOfClassesWithMaxStudents` of classes with `maxNumberOfStudents` and (y-numberOfClassesWithMaxStudents)` with `minNumberOfStudents`

Comment: You mean we don't need a `floor` as majority of languages would do it automatically for int/int?

Comment: @sha I'm convinced assigning it to an int would just truncate the value of floor, which it would do anyway for x/y, so yes it wouldn't be needed. @rmaddy would simply casting `x` and `y` to floating point values be enough given that this would allow for floating point division? Final code: https://gist.github.com/MaxKramer/663705fdd2d81c7c7c0e

Comment: @max_ Nevermind. I don't know what I was thinking. Integer division has the same result as using `floor` so the posted code works fine regardless of the types of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without having some indication of which class you are working with.

An 'incremental' use would be to calculate what the 'next; class size would be given the remaining students, and remaining classes:

```
int remainingStudents = 97;
int remainingClasses = 5;

int nextClass = nextClassSize(remainingStudents, remainingClasses);
```

where the `nextClassSize(...)` is something like:

```
return (remainingStudents - 1 + remainingClasses) / remainingClasses;
```

Putting this in [ideone here](http://ideone.com/WIWOSu)